# Application does not work properly in background without Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, multitasking

I'm building an activity analyzer application for iPhone and I use iOS 7. In order to do these i use CMMotionManager and I access accelerometer data.After this I write the datum to database. My application has to work also in background and I used queues, GCD, blocks and other such things in my code to do this properly. Problem is, all of these are working properly when iPhone is plugged in with Xcode but if I run the app without Xcode, app runs about 4 or 5 minutes.After, it is terminated.What is the reason for this?

Comment: On which device are you testing? Do you have background execution enabled in system settings?

Comment: I test on iPhone 4."Background App Refresh" enabled in system settings. If is there anything wrong in my app,it should not work properly with Xcode, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

iOS apps can only run in background, if they fit in one of apples defined background modes such as "App registers for location updates","App provides Voice over IP services","App plays audio","App processes Newsstand Kit downloads","App communicates using CoreBluetooth"",App shares data using CoreBluetooth" and a few more. All background modes you will find in xcode in the capabilities section auf your project(click on project name upper left->mainwindow->second tab).

if your app fits into one of these modes, you must enable this in your app.plist by setting the checkbox in the capabilities section.

if your app doesn't fit in any of these modes you can run in background only a limited amount of time and then iOS stops all activities.

For testing you could start any background mode. but when your app shall be reviewed for deploying via app store apple will reject the app if you use the background mode without legitimation.

Comment: I have already defined the background mode from capabilities section. My app reads accelerometer values 40 times per second and write them to the database.This why I selected location updates and background fetch sections.It works properly when iPhone plugged in with Xcode.But it does not work without Xcode. I'm wondering its why.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that iOS 7 (actually all versions of iOS) will suspend a background task, and potentially terminate it if it's misbehaving, only certain kinds of apps can keep running. Here is the apple doc on it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

So, given your situation, you'd most likely have to "lie" about what type of app your app actually is, which will get you rejected from the app store.

If you do decide to go the route of a hack, be very careful about battery life, cpu usage, and memory usage, as there is a reason apple did this.

FYI: The "type" is set in your Info.plist file.